# model? field related with specific field of other model?

Tags: django

Assume I have a model. I would like to create a second one whic is related to a specific field of first one. Can we right something like this? `models.ManytoManyField(Userprofile.whishlist`

```
class Userprofile(models.model):
     wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='user_wishlist')
     ...
class Rating(models.model):
      post = models.ManytoManyField(Userprofile.whishlist,...)
```

Comment: M2M setup does not have an option like this. You can create a custom `through` relation to achieve this setup.

Comment: Just Info: It can be done if it were an FK by using a [`ForeignKey.to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)